# java first 10000 prime numbers error

Tags: java

I have a method that is supposed to display all the prime numbers `0-10000` recursively, but if I try to make it print the 10000th prime number a stack overflow exception is thrown.

```
public void One(int i) {
    int n;
    if(i<10000){
        One(i+1);
    }
    for(n=2;n<i;n++) {
        if(i%n==0){
            break; 
        }
    }
    if(i==n){
        System.out.print(i+","); 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your if statement where it says

```
if(i < 10000){...}
```

to:

```
if(i < 10001){...}
```

or:

```
if(i <= 10000){...}
```

Comment: Why? How it is relevant to this context?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it all i had to do was switch

```
if(i<10000){
One(i+1);
}
```

to the bottom instead of being in the top.

Comment: You have solved your problem. Now mark this answer as correct solution.